# Override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer is not working in custom module magento2

Tags: overrides, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to override `layer.php` file in my custom module but it is not taking override file, it is loading core file only

Here is my `di.xml` `file -> path : [namespace][module_name][etc] -> di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="[namespace]\[module_name]\Model\Layer" />
```

Here is my custom module `layer.php` file Path : `[namespace][module_name][Model][Layer.php]`

```
namespace [namespace][module_name]\Model;

class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        var_dump("local");
        die;
    }
}
```

When I run the code it is not load file from my custom module.

Can you please help me I am not getting how to load `layer.php` file from my custom module.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you set a preference for the Layer file or have otherwise instructed the Dependency Injection to use your file? Merely placing your file into your module will not make Magento choose your implementation.

Comment: It's also likely that you want to use a plugin for the getProductCollection() method instead

Comment: Did you create `etc/module.xml` and `registration.php`?

Comment: @PY Yick, Yes I have created the module.xml and registration.php file. My module is working fine but the only problem is layer.php file not loading from my custom module

Comment: @Kristof, the Same way I have override category.php file from the model but it is working fine. I am not getting why only layer.php file not override. 
I didn't try to use the plugin, Let me try might be it will solve my problem. 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you rename `layer.php` to `Layer.php`?

Comment: Yes, I have renamed but still no luck, it's not working

Comment: I have also the same issue